# Continuity of distance between a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a closed set $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed set. Show that the distance function
$$x \to d(x, A) = \inf \{ \|x - a\|; a \in A\}$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My idea is to prove the continuity with $\epsilon, \delta$ definition. For $\epsilon > 0$, I need to find $\delta > 0$ so

$$|\inf \{ \|x_0 - a\|; a \in A\} - \inf \{ \|x_1 - a\|; a \in A\}| < \epsilon$$

if $\|x_0 - x_1\| < \delta$.

Assume $\|a_0 - x_0\| = d(x_0, A)$ and  $\|a_1 - x_1\| = d(x_1, A)$. Because $A$ is closed, $A^c$ must be open therefore $a_0, a_1$ can not in $A^c$, hence $a_0, a_1 \in A$.

This is where I am completely stucked.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to proof it for compact sets frist, bc then this infimum is attained. You will just need the triangle inequality and the 2nd (or reverse) triangle inequality.

If you understood this, you can extend the proof easily to closed sets by not taking a minimzer, but sth which is suffenicently close

Comment: @user940347 as $\{x\}$ is compact and $A$ is closed, $A$ doesn't have to be bounded for the infimum to be attained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: in any metric space, suppose $x, y$ are two points with $d(x, y) < \delta$, and suppose $a$ is the closest point in $A$ to $x$. Then $d(y, A) \leq d(y, a) \leq d(x, y) + d(x, a)$ by the triangle inequality, which means $d(y, A) - d(x, A)$ has an upper bound of what?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $x_0\in \Bbb R^n$. We need to find a $\delta>0$, such that $d(x,x_0)<\delta \Rightarrow |d(x,A)-d(x_0,A)|<\epsilon$. By choosing $\delta:=\epsilon$, we can verify that $d(x,A)-d(x_0,A)=inf\{||x-a||: a\in A\}-inf\{||x_0-a||:a\in A\}\leq ||x-x_0||+inf\{||x_0-a||:a\in A\}-inf\{||x_0-a||: a\in A\}=||x-x_0||=d(x,x_0)<\epsilon. (1)$

Analogous thoughts give us that $-\epsilon<d(x,A)-d(x_0,A). (2)$

Finally by $(1),(2)$ we have what requested.